# Read data from text file print to terminal and new text file

Tags: java, text-files, printwriter

I want to read data from a text file and print the output to both the terminal and a text file. I have a loop that reads for numbers and one that reads for non-numerical characters, but nothing is printing out to the terminal. i am new to programming.
I am transforming an old project to a new one by the way.

```
package studenttester;


public class Student
{
    private String name;
    double quizScore;
    double quizAverage;
    private int numQuizzes;
    String grade;


  /**
 * Returns the name of a student
 * 
 * @return the name of the student 
 */
     public Student (String inName)
    {
            name = inName;
            quizAverage = 0;
            quizScore = 0;
            numQuizzes = 0;
    }
    public String getName()

    {
        return name;
    }

 /**
 * Adds a quiz score to the total quiz score of the student
 * 
 * @param score the score of a quiz     
 */
      void addQuiz(int score)
    {

        numQuizzes += 1; 
        quizScore += score; 

    } 

/**
 * Returns the total score of all the quizzes combined that student took
 * 
 * @return the value of score
 */


    double getTotalScore()
    {

        return quizScore; 

    } 


/**
 * Returns the average score of all the quizzes a student took
 * 
 * @return
 */
    double getAverageScore() 
    {

        return quizScore / numQuizzes; 

    } 
}


package studenttester;


 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;



public class StudentTester {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    System.out.println("Student Name         Number of Quizzes                       Average");

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("quizScores.txt"));

    String studentName = "", first="", last="";
 while (!reader.hasNext("-10"))
{

}
while (reader.hasNextDouble())
{
        first = first+reader.next();
        studentName = last + first;
}

Student newStudent = new Student(studentName);

while (reader.hasNextDouble() && !reader.hasNext("-10"))
    {
    System.out.printf("");
    }

{
           // writer.close;
}


}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "red underline" means an compiler error, I guess.
Have a look to your while loop, it seems to be wrong.
Try ...

```
while (reader.hasNextDouble() && (!reader.hasNext("-10")))
    System.out.printf("");
}
reader.close();
```

instead.

Comment: I actually ended up figuring that one out myself. Thanks! I am still unsure what to have for the System.out.printf("");. I am trying to print out Students' names and the number of quizzes they took and their average on the quizzes.